# Compare two date or datetime variables in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to run this but I get an error:

```
DECLARE @today_date DATETIME = GETDATE(), 
        @order_date DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT @order_date = order_date 
FROM app_orderbook 
WHERE order_no = 1;

SELECT (@order_date < @today_date);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near '<'.

For completeness' sake, the `order_date` is a `datetime` column from `tblOrders`. I am not able to correct this after searching for guidance and hint.

How do I resolve this? For simplicity, you can even comment out 2nd SQL statement. Still it shows error.

Comment: T-SQL has no "true" booleans, so a statement like `SELECT x < y` is always illegal; such expression are only allowed in particular contexts where conditions are allowed. `SELECT CASE WHEN x < y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` would work.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which is a short hand `CASE` expression function.

Comment: SQL Server supports the [`bit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type. (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.) There is a [boolean](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."

Comment: Thank you  @Jeroen Mostert for explaining it beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

following @ThmA advise, it should look like this:

```
DECLARE @today_date DATETIME = GETDATE(), 
        @order_date DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT @order_date = order_date 
FROM app_orderbook 
WHERE order_no = 1;

SELECT IIF(@order_date < @today_date, 'True', 'False') as ComparisonResult;
```

OR

```
SELECT IIF(@order_date < @today_date, 1, 0) as ComparisonResult;
```